# Show only Subsites as drop down menu

Tags: navigation, top-link-bar

I have a site collection on SP Standard 2010.  I want to achieve a menu flyout like so:

```
A  B   C
a  b   c
a2 b2  c2
```

A, B, C are  the parent menu and a,b,c are the submenu very easy.
I have made sure the publising features on the sitecollections and the subsites have been activated.

What do i need to do to get the dropdown menu  as i have tried to create a site collection A and then created a subsite a and a2 but i don't get the dropdown feature even after changing the staticdisplay and maxdisplay setting in the masterpages.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have three site collections or just one? If A is a site collection, then the OOB navigation will not include B or C. You can add them manually via the Navigation link in Site Settings.

Comment: Sorry lets A is a site collection but B & C are subsites

Answer (score 0):

This can be found under site settings -> navigation